# Phraseology definition

Tags: phrase-structure, phrases, lexical-relations

What's difference between free-phrase and fixed phrase?

Because for some linguist differentiate phraseme (fixed phrase) into 3 part, vollidiomatizität, teilidiomatizität und nichtidiomatizität.